About page on Django app is showing Page not found
Django about pageTried running about page on a Django project using sublime text editor. The project shows page not found each time i refresh the browser. I have tried every method i came across.
My Project structure looks something like this on sublime text editor.
-DjangoProjects
   -myfirstproject
   -myfirstproject
    /*-pyache
    /*-init.py
    /*-asgi.py
    /*-settings.py
    /*-urls.py
    /*-views.py
    /*-wsgi.py
    -db.sqlite3
    /*-manage.py

     -Urls.py

      from.django contrib import admin
      from django.urls import path
      from . import views

      urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('about/', views.about),
      ]

I expect the project to show the content of the about page. Without returning the 404 error response.
        -views.py

        from django.http import HttpResponse


        def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("This is about page.")

      
    
      -settings.py

"""
Django settings for myfirstproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-4576&8@l##a!=-yjbl-5d3%o&hg2rx3l3j$- 
xxw5pwp#ft)+z)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myfirstproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myfirstproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password- 
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 



     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation
     .UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
     },
    {
      'NAME': 
     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation
     .MinimumLengthValidator',
      },
     {
        'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation
    .CommonPasswordValidator',
     },
    {
    'NAME': 
   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation
   .NumericPasswordValidator',
   },
 
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto- 
field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


   -manage.py

 """
 ASGI config for myfirstproject project.

 It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named 
 ``application``.

 For more information on this file, see
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/
 """

 import os

 from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 
 'myfirstproject.settings')

  application = get_asgi_application()



Your urlpatterns list has a syntax error where you have a missing comma. (If you're not getting this error have you even saved the file?) 2. The url you're hitting is /product while the url specified in the code is /about.


@AbdulAzizBarkat i included the comma its still not working. Then the /product url is a mistake. Tested the /about url it shows the same error.

Can you show your Project Structure?

@ManojKamble i added the project structure.

In you main urls.py you should call views.index.
Old urls.py :
from.django contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
 path('about/', views.urls) 
]

Upadated urls.py:
from.django contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('about/', views.index)  # Changes Done Here
]

